# Can I avoid a looping through a vector for the same operation (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I have a vector and have to do the same calculation for every element of the vector. Its a Similarity measure for categorical data that need the frequency of a given value. In this case I want to calculate the distance between two points a and b of x

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [2, 1, 1]])
a = x[0]; b= x[1]

pairwise_dist = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    freq_a = sum(x[:, i] == a[i])
    freq_b = sum(x[:, i] == b[i])

    match = 1
    missmatch = 1/(1 + np.log(freq_a)*np.log(freq_b))
            
    pairwise_dist.append((a[i] == b[i]) * match + (a[i] != b[i]) * missmatch)

dist = sum(pairwise_dist)/len(a)
```

Its always the same operations and its always only the i-th element of the vector.
Shouldn't it be possible to vectorize this?

Comment: This would be a straight forward numpy cacluation if you didn't have the `mismatch` variable in the middle of the loop. For example, if `a` and `b` are np.arrays, you get another array from `c=a+b`. Can reorder/restructure the calculation so every operation is on an appropriately shaped array to calculate `dist` as an array? `np.where()` might serve the purpose.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's broadcasting can handle pretty much all of what your loop does. The only special behavior you need is to use `numpy.sum` with an `axis` argument when computing the `freq_a` and `freq_b` values, since you don't want to sum over all the axes at once (since that would give you a scalar, not a vector).

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [2, 1, 1]])
a = x[0]
b = x[1]

freq_a = np.sum(x == a, axis=0)
freq_b = np.sum(x == b, axis=0)

match = 1
missmatch = 1/(1 + np.log(freq_a)*np.log(freq_b))

pairwise_dist = (a == b) * match + (a != b) * missmatch

dist = np.sum(pairwise_dist)/len(a)
```

Note that while this is an accurate translation of your existing code, I'm not sure it does anything useful. It always computes a `dist` of `1.0`, regardless of input. But so does the original code, so I guess it's bug-compatible!